# Recurring dreams

Tags: torah-study, nevua-prophecy, dream

What is the significance of a recurring dream in Judaism?

I remember in the story of Yosef...that a dream repeating twice in a night means the matter is at hand to be fulfilled but it it repeats with some time in between there is yet time for it to come true.

Does anyone have more sources on these concepts?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.55b.20?lang=bi

> וְאָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן, שְׁלֹשָׁה חֲלוֹמוֹת מִתְקַיְּימִין: חֲלוֹם
> שֶׁל שַׁחֲרִית, וַחֲלוֹם שֶׁחָלַם לוֹ חֲבֵירוֹ, וַחֲלוֹם שֶׁנִּפְתַּר
> בְּתוֹךְ חֲלוֹם. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמֵר: אַף חֲלוֹם שֶׁנִּשְׁנָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר:
> ״וְעַל הִשָּׁנוֹת הַחֲלוֹם וְגוֹ׳״.
>
> Rabbi Yoḥanan also said: Three dreams are fulfilled: A dream of the
> morning, a dream that one’s fellow dreamed about him, and a dream that
> is interpreted within a dream. And some say that a dream that is
> repeated several times is also fulfilled, as it is stated: “And for
> that the dream was doubled unto Pharaoh twice, it is because the thing
> is established by God, and God will shortly bring it to pass” (Genesis
> 41:32).